# Instance deployment: The Docker container unexpectedly ended after it was started

Tags: docker, gitlab, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, cicd

hi guys not sure what im doing wrong here but when ever i upload my project docker image to elastic beanstalk i get this error: Instance deployment: The Docker container unexpectedly ended after it was started. I am new to this and i am not sure why this happens please help if you can.

docker image

```
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --force
COPY . .
ENV APP_PORT 8080
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "node", "app.js" ]
```

.gitlab-ci.yml file

```
  - build
  - run

variables:
  APP_NAME: ${CI_PROJECT_NAME}
  APP_VERSION: "1.0.0"`enter code here`
  S3_BUCKET: "${S3_BUCKET}"
  AWS_ID: ${MY_AWS_ID}
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${MY_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${MY_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
  AWS_REGION: us-east-1
  AWS_PLATFORM: Docker

create_eb_version:
  stage: build
  image: python:latest
  allow_failure: false
  script: |
    pip install awscli #Install awscli tools

    echo "Creating zip file ${APP_NAME}"
    python zip.py ${APP_NAME}

    echo "Creating AWS Version Label"
    AWS_VERSION_LABEL=${APP_NAME}-${APP_VERSION}-${CI_PIPELINE_ID}
    S3_KEY="$AWS_VERSION_LABEL.zip"

    echo "Uploading to S3"
    aws s3 cp ${APP_NAME}.zip s3://${S3_BUCKET}/${S3_KEY} --region ${AWS_REGION}

    echo "Creating app version"
    aws elasticbeanstalk create-application-version \
      --application-name ${APP_NAME} \
      --version-label $AWS_VERSION_LABEL \
      --region ${AWS_REGION} \
      --source-bundle S3Bucket=${S3_BUCKET},S3Key=${S3_KEY} \
      --description "${CI_COMMIT_DESCRIPTION}" \
      --auto-create-application \
  only:
    refs:
      - main

deploy_aws_eb:
  stage: run
  image: coxauto/aws-ebcli
  when: manual
  script: |
    AWS_VERSION_LABEL=${APP_NAME}-${APP_VERSION}-${CI_PIPELINE_ID}

    echo "Deploying app to tf test"
    eb init -i ${APP_NAME} -p ${AWS_PLATFORM} -k ${AWS_ID} --region ${AWS_REGION}
    echo "Deploying to enviroment"
    eb deploy ${APP_ENVIROMENT_NAME} --version ${AWS_VERSION_LABEL}
    echo "done"
  only:
    refs:
      - main
```

Comment: you can view the logs,that might give some clue

$ docker logs <container_name> .


Another potential cause of this issue is that the Docker container is not receiving the necessary resources (e.g. CPU, memory, storage) to run properly
$ docker stats <container_name>

Comment: Can you briefly describe what `app.js` contains? Knowing if it starts an http server listening on `APP_PORT` or not will be helpful to know why the container might be crashing early.

Comment: const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT) || 3001; this is the port that my application is listening on

Comment: I got it to work my node version was old changed the node version to 16 and also replaced APP_PORT with PORT

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work my node version in my docker file was set to 10 and not 16  changed the node version to 16 and also replaced APP_PORT with PORT because that's what I named it